# How to code a automatic reset of checkboxes in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a list of tasks, in checklist format, that my staff has to complete everyday. Every time they check off one of the boxes (Column A) the column next to it (Column B) updates with the time Column A was updated. Is there a way to make the checked check boxes automatically reset by a specific time? After the day is over and we close, I'd like for the checkboxes to reset for the next day. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

[image]

Don't have a lot of coding experience so I wouldn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

additionally you must set a trigger so that the function runs every day at the desired time.

```js
function changeCheckbox() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Replace "Sheet name" with the name of your spreadsheet.
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A"); // Cell range with checkboxes

  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] === true) {
      range.getCell(i + 1, 1).setValue(false);
    }
  }
}
```